# Getting a div to display none on page load and then display block when the function runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

In a sequence of animations I have a small bug that I finally figured out what was causing it. On all of the animations, I am running delays to sequence them in. For those divs, I style them to `display:none` and then I fade them in.

Well for this particular animation, I am `toggle` sliding a "mask" off of it, so not fading anything in like normal. This was causing an overlapping over my other divs to where I thought I had a `z-index` issue this whole time. Well, not the case. I need help figuring out how I keep my div `home-learn` displaying none until the delay has processed.

Here is the code:

```
#home-learn {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2.3em;
    z-index: 99;
    display: none;
}
#curtain-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0085A1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}   

$(function(){
    $('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');
    $("#curtain-div").delay(15800).toggle("slide", {
        direction: "right"
      }, 1000);
});
```

If I take out `$('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');` then nothing shows at all. How can I get `home-learn` to display once the animation starts (after the delay)?

```
<div class="blue">
    <div id="hand-wrap"><img src="/images/hand.png" class="hand" alt="HELLO"></div>
    <span class="hand-text">HELLO</span>
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="spinner top topright"></div>
        <div class="spinner top topleft"></div>
        <div class="spinner bottom bottomleft"></div>
        <div class="spinner bottom bottomright"></div>
        <div class="mask q2"></div>
        <div class="mask q4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="circle-text">We're Optimum<br>Designs</div>
    <div class="aqua">
        <div id="aqua-text1">We transform ideas...</div>
        <div id="aqua-text2">...into reality.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="blue-home-text">We build beautiful, engaging sites for companies both large and small.</div>
    <div id="home-learn">
        <div id="curtain-div"></div>
        Discover more...
    </div>
```

Comment: can we see the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a JS function to trigger animation of elements sequentially -

For e.g., if you want the sequence of DIVs to load as DIV1 > DIV2 > DIV3 > DIV4 -

**HTML**

```
    <div class="class1 ani"></div>
    <div class="classwithanimation ani"></div>
    <div class="classafteranimation ani"></div>
    <div class="class4 ani"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".ani").delay(1000).each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Accordingly, in your CSS file, you can incorporate whatever CSS animation you want to trigger with `display:none` & `position:absolute` attributes. The "ani" JS ensures the next element is only loaded after the previous element has loaded.

I know this is not the exact solution, but thought you could customise this to your need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
$("#curtain-div").delay(2000).toggle("slide", function(){
    $('#home-learn').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Add background color

```
#home-learn {
    color: #FFF;
    background: blue none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2.3em;
    z-index: 99;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Add background color as font color is #FFF (white).